# Possible closed form or approximation?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, closed-form

Does it have some closed form or approximation ? I tried on my own but i am not getting any idea regarding this.

$$\sum_{k_1=k}^{M}\sum_{k_2=k}^{M}\frac{k_1^{-\gamma}  k_2^{-\gamma}  {{M-k}\choose{k_1-k}}{{M-k_1}\choose{k_2-k}}}{{M\choose k_1}{M \choose k_2}}$$
One implied relation is "$k_1+k_2 \leq M+k$".

Please share hint or solution or direction.